# WPF - Scrolling with mouse wheel freezes DataGrid with custom Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping, expander

I have modified the style for the Expander to be able to stretch the content in the header of a group in a DataGrid. The style is based on the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296(v=vs.110).aspx) template. It works fine but when i scroll with the mouse wheel the program freezes. Scrolling with the Scrollbar works fine! Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton"
             TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="Border"
      CornerRadius="0"
      BorderThickness="0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                  Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandededArrow">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                  Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid>
            <Path x:Name="CollapsedArrow"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ForegroundColor}" />
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
            <Path x:Name="ExpandededArrow"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Data="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ForegroundColor}" />
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}" 
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter  Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="Content"
                          BorderThickness="0"
                          CornerRadius="0" Visibility="Collapsed">

                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the xaml i use a DataGrid with VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" for performance.

```
<DataGrid Margin="10, 5, 10, 10" 
    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" >
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left">Label to the left</Label>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right">Button to the right</Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,15"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander Background="Transparent" IsExpanded="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" >
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to answer this, but I ran across this question when looking for an answer to a similar problem with a ListBox that used IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping.  Here's my solution.

My problem was that the GroupStyle.ContainerStyle had a margin that changed the vertical size:

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0" />
  </Style>
</GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

For me, I just removed the ContainerStyle all together, and moved the margin to the HeaderTemplate.

I see that the XAML in the question also has a margin on the GroupItem's style that would change its height.  Perhaps that's the culprit?

Hope this helps the next person.